# Reso felice in una parola

Tags: word-choice

Sto cercando una parola per dire "reso più felice" o qualcosa del genere, ma in una parola sola.
Voglio descrivere una persona triste con cui ho parlato e che si sente meno triste e mi saluta ****.

**** è la parola che cerco. Non felice, è troppo, non consolata (perché i problemi ancora ci sono), ma resa più felice, appunto, che si sente un po' meglio. Esiste una tale parola?

Comment: “confortato”, “riconfortato”, qualcosa del genere?

Comment: Potrebbe essere "alleviato"?

Comment: Sì, simile, ma non proprio. Qualcosa come "lusingata dalla sua attenzione", "felicitata" (se fosse una parola!).

Comment: @user [*Felicitata*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/felicitare/) esiste, ma in tempi moderni ha assunto un diverso significato...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forse [**rallegrata**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/rallegrare/)?

> **rallegrare** v. tr. [der. di *allegro*, col pref. *r-*] (*io rallégro*, ecc.). – 1. Rendere allegro o più allegro, sollevare o risollevare l’umore; allietare: *r. la compagnia con qualche barzelletta*; più com., destare in altri un sentimento di allegrezza, d’intima gioia, far piacere (contr. di *rattristare*): *mi hai veramente rallegrato col tuo ritorno; il suo successo non può che rallegrarmi; la notizia ci rallegrò; consolare: all’Italia Afflitta di regali ire straniere Voli improvviso a rallegrarla il carme* (Foscolo).
>
> (Dal vocabolario Treccani)

Sempre il Treccani ci fornisce una lista di sinonimi che potrebbe essere utile:

> allegrare, allietare, deliziare, dilettare, divertire, (lett.) felicitare, ricreare,...

Comment: Bello, felicitata. Cioè, in tempi moderni, come lo intenderesti?

Comment: @user Il primo significato che associo a *felicitare* è *congratulare*, come nel [significato 3. del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/felicitare/), probabilmente influenzato dall'uso di *felicitazioni* (che è di gran lunga più comune di *felicitare*)

Comment: Forse allietata, più che rallegrata, rende quello che voglio. Grazie.